# TYPO3 10.4 - manual installation of backend language

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

The following problem: On the customer's server, I get the message that language packs are not available when I download them. My assumption is that some server settings are blocking the download.

The simplest solution for me was, of course, that I have the language packs locally and can simply upload them.

I uploaded the l10n folder, but in the user settings I get the message `The selected language <my language> is not available before the language files are installed.`

Can anyone tell me where I may have forgotten to set something? Everything I've found so far suggests that I just need to throw everything into the l10n and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The path of the XLF files depends if the installation is based on composer or not.

- With composer: `var/labels`
- Without composer: `typo3conf/l10n`

Additionally in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` a list of availalable languages is set:

```php
'EXTCONF' => [
        'lang' => [
            'availableLanguages' => [
                'de',
                'fi',
                'fr',
                'it',
                'nl',
                'no',
                'sl',
                'sv',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

---

So yes, if the files are at the correct location + configuration is set + cache cleared, then it should work out fine.

Comment: Thanks!
I don't know why, but there where language files in `typo3conf/l10n` too so i didn't searched elsewhere.